# How to calculate the tank boost system for the displacement feed system?

Tags: rockets, engines, engine-design, amateur-rocketry

There is a liquid rocket engine running on two components: `highly concentrated hydrogen peroxide` and `kerosene`, fuel vapor is stored in two tanks under some pressure, how to calculate a supply system with a displacement gas so that the supply pressure remains constant?

*Using a pressure reducer is one of the ideas, but are there ways to do it without them?*